Sensible auto-completion at point with python-lsp-server and rope auto-import enabled in emacs
I use emacs with python-lsp-server (pylsp) for python development (I attached my setup below).
Pylsp supports auto-import via rope. You have to enable it by setting lsp-pylsp-plugins-rope-autoimport-enabled to true (c.f. here).
In principle it works but my problem is that it clutters my completion-at-point popup most of the time. Here is a screenshot:

As you can see I am about to write constraints again. I would like to get the local variable as the top (or at least one of the top) candidates for completion. Instead I get a lot of auto-import suggestions (first). This happens a lot and makes the auto-import practically unusable for me.
I would prefer the auto-import suggestions to be a bit less dominant. Local objects or imports from my own code should be prioritized (in some way). Is there a way to accomplish that? Idealy I would like to see the auto-completions for auto-imports only on demand (something like enabling auto-import by a command). If this was possible ordering the import-suggestions would still be interesting but not as important anymore.
I looked into the documentation of rope. I couldn't find any settings to fine tune ordering of completion suggestions.
I have seen that there is a code action to import missing symbols (c.f. autoimport.md in the pylsp repo). This would be a workaround. Unfortunately lsp-mode for emacs only enables this code action together with completions.
I use corfu as completion-at-point framework. I replaced it with company but I get exactly the same suggestions in the same order.
My setup (minimal example)
This is not my actual development setup but a minimal example to reproduce my problem.
I use a virtual environment (micromamba) with python 3.12.3 installed and the following packages via pip:
black
isort
python-lsp-server
pylsp-mypy
python-lsp-ruff
pylsp-rope
ipython

I use emacs 29.3 with the following init.el file:
;; init.el

;; Activate MELPA
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(setq package-menu-hide-low-priority nil)
(setq package-archive-priorities '(("gnu" . 20) ("melpa" . 10)))

(package-initialize nil)

(setq initial-frame-alist '((fullscreen . maximized))
      auto-save-default nil
      inhibit-startup-screen t
      make-backup-files nil)

;; lsp integration
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure
  :init
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-show-with-mouse t
        lsp-ui-doc-position 'at-point
        lsp-pylsp-plugins-ruff-enabled t
        lsp-pylsp-plugins-mypy-enabled t
        lsp-pylsp-plugins-rope-autoimport-enabled t) ; <<<--- For auto-import
  :hook((python-mode . lsp)
        (lsp-mode . lsp-enable-which-key-integration))
  :commands lsp)

;; completion-at-point framework (`company` works too) 
(use-package corfu
  :ensure
  :demand
  :custom
  (corfu-auto t)
  (corfu-quit-at-boundary 'separator)
  (corfu-quit-no-match 'separator)
  (corfu-scroll-margin 0)
  (corfu-separator ?\s)
  (corfu-popupinfo-delay '(0.5 . 0.2))
  :config
  (global-corfu-mode)
  (corfu-popupinfo-mode +1))


I think this completely improper place to file what is in fact a bug report. Please, report it at https://github.com/python-rope/rope/issues or https://github.com/python-rope/pylsp-rope/issues.
